# How to say 'Already I know you' in a formal way?

Tags: politeness

I attended a seminar given by a great scholar few years back. Then I had a chance to meet him in one of  my colleague family function. My friend introduced me to him. I said:

> Already I know you. I have attended one of your seminar.

But I thought it was little bit rude and too straightforward.

Is there any other way to start a conversation or introduce ourselves to a  famous person?

Comment: Perhaps a few pleasantries at the beginning would have sounded smoother e.g. "What a pleasure to meet you...; "Lovely to meet you, I once attended a seminar of yours..." etc. But sometimes it's nice not to hear all the fluff and hear someone who is cheerfully direct.

Comment: For almost all contexts it would normally be *I know you **already*** or *I **already** know you* if you wanted to use those four words.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually met and spoke with the person:

> Hello, we've already met.  If you recall  ...
>
> Hello, we've actually been previously introduced ...

If you've just gone to see one of his lectures:

> Hello, actually I attended one of your lectures ...
>
> Hello, I actually know you, I came to see you when you were at (A) to give a lecture on (B).

Or if it's, for example, a famous celebrity (if you don't mind being cliche):

> Hello I'm (A) and of course I know who you are.  I am a big fan of your work.

Comment: You can also include "You probably don't remember, but we met once when..."